# I want the key columns of a nested json blob

Tags: json, key

{
"xyz": {
"1": "a",
"2": "b",
"3": "c",
"4": "d",
"5": {
"6": {
"7": [
{
"8": "e",
"9": "f",
"10": "g",
"11": "h"
},
{
"8": "i",
"9": "j",
"10": "k",
"11": "l"
},
{
"8": "m",
"9": "n",
"10": "o",
"11": "p"
}
]
}
}
}
}

I want the output to be
1, 2, 3, 4, .. ,11

All the nested keys

I tried keys(), but I am expecting it to show nested keys as well

Comment: What language is this expected to be in?  What did you actually try (as opposed to what method did you somehow use)?  What is the actual, full output you would want from this sample input, and by what logic?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you expect, but here's a JavaScript recursive solution to get all the nested keys:

```
function getNestedKeys(obj, parentKeys = []) {
  const keys = [];

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      keys.push(key);

      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        const nestedKeys = getNestedKeys(obj[key], [...parentKeys, key]);
        keys.push(...nestedKeys);
      }
    }
  }

  return [...parentKeys, ...keys];
}
```